# __len__ can't return big numbers

Tags: python

The following code:

```
class Container:

    def __len__(self):
        return 10**100

c = Container()
print(len(c))
```

returns

> OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer

I've read this issue [has been marked as WON'T FIX](https://bugs.python.org/issue21444) but perhaps it was fixed in another issue? Any workaround besides using custom attribute for storing container size?

I'm using Python 3.6.9 and it has not been fixed in this version.

Comment: "... and it has not been fixed in this version ..." – so when they said "WON'T FIX", they actually *meant* it.

Comment: CPython 3.8.0 also has this restriction, and there is no reason to assume it will change in the future. This is part of the CPython C-API.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need this? A purpose of ``__len__`` is primarily to internally size arrays, which cannot be as big.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Sometimes you may want to implement custom containers for which don't need to store all possible elements (e.g., because they are generated on the fly) but you still you know the total number of elements. For instance you know that `product(*lists)` generates large number of combinations but you don't need to store them in memory.

Comment: @dzieciou Doesn't even need a custom container. I get a similar error for `len(range(2**31))` as well (on my 32-bit Python).

Comment: @dzieciou I'm not questioning how one could *have* an object that expands to such a size, I'm wondering why you *need to know* the size of such an object. Basically, I want to rule out that you are trying to solve an XY problem. You cannot reify such an object - even at 1 byte per element, the total is about 8 EiB. You cannot iterate such an object - even at 1ns per element, that takes 300 years.

Answer (score 5):

This has not changed in any way and there is no workaround. It is a documented CPython implementation detail.

> #### [`object.__len__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__)
>
> Called to implement the built-in function `len()`.
>   Should return the length of the object, an integer `>= 0`. Also, an
>   object that doesn’t define a `__bool__()` method and whose `__len__()`
>   method returns zero is considered to be false in a Boolean context.
>
> **CPython implementation detail:** In CPython, the length is required to
>   be at most `sys.maxsize`. If the length is larger than `sys.maxsize` some
>   features (such as `len()`) may raise OverflowError. To prevent raising
>   `OverflowError` by truth value testing, an object must define a
>   `__bool__()` method.

Note that the maximum value is `9223372036854775807` on a 64 bit machine.

> #### [sys.maxsize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize)
>
> An integer giving the maximum value a variable of type
>   Py_ssize_t can take. It’s usually `2**31 - 1` on a 32-bit platform and
>   `2**63 - 1` on a 64-bit platform.

---

The restriction is due to `__len__` being a Python representation of several C-API calls to get container lengths. [The C-API requires a type of `Py_ssize_t` for this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0353/), which has the observed restrictions.

> [**Py_ssize_t PySequence_Length(PyObject *o)**](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/mapping.html#c.PyMapping_Length)
>
> Returns the number of objects in
>   sequence `o` on success, and `-1` on failure. This is equivalent to the
>   Python expression `len(o)`.

---

Since `OverflowError` is a documented behaviour, it is acceptable for objects that *might* be too large for `__len__` to provide it anyway. For example, the builtin `range` can overflow on `len`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> len(range(sys.maxsize))
9223372036854775807
>>> len(range(sys.maxsize + 1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t
```

If the precise length is needed, objects are free to implement a separate method to return the length without using `len`.