# Division breaking down for large numbers

Tags: python

I was coding the Colatz Conjecture and did a trial run with very large numbers 20^200, but when i ran it the first iteration was not the expected value.

```
VERDE = "\033[1;42m"
ROJO = "\033[0;41m"


numero = int(input("Que numero quieres meter: "))
print(len(str(numero)))
print(numero)


while numero != 2:
    if numero % 2 == 0:
        numero = int(numero/2)
        print(ROJO, numero)
    else: 
        numero = 3*numero +1
        print(VERDE, numero)
```

it does work for small number

20^200 is 160693804425899027554196209234116260252220299378279283530137600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

and (20^200)/2 is
80346902212949513777098104617058130126110149689139641765068800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

but in my code it outputed
80346902212949511345248234734334423967696097365434852542864353535792391032371609753125488732036784167010019952681082654533118303915755562167778520150278530021949710970298904939065778331648989109467961581227009030403910900141141641181563086906360222220470452224

why the difference, is it because it is a large number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers in python (and all other programming languages) are stored in memory as [data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-170) occupying a certain memory space.

This means that data type can store only certain bytes of memory, meaning they have limits for number precision they can account for.

In Python 3 actually the matter is also more complex. It is well explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63923040/21024780).

So in Python3 integers can potentially be greater/lower than the usual `int` data type limits. Then why in your program you still encounter problems?

That is because you still divide your number by 2 with `numero/2`. That makes the value `numero/2` become a `float`.
And floats in Python can only have a certain precision. This means that any digit that goes beyond that level of precision will be practically be stored as a random number.

In your case, since the number you are considering is even, you can get away with applying Python's [floor division](https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-double-slash-operator-floor-division/) with a double forward slash (`//`):

```py
VERDE = "\033[1;42m"
ROJO = "\033[0;41m"


numero = int(input("Que numero quieres meter: "))
print(len(str(numero)))
print(numero)


while numero != 2:
    if numero % 2 == 0:
        numero = numero//2
        print(ROJO, numero)
    else: 
        numero = 3*numero +1
        print(VERDE, numero)
```

Comment: This does not apply to Python, it has integers of unlimited size.

Comment: Sorry I explained it badly. I edited my answer.

Comment: You still didn't present the obvious solution.

Comment: Well I did now :)

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Once you replace the `/` with `//` the `int()` becomes redundant.