# Length of giant list-like objects in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, instance-variables, largenumber

I'm creating a list-like object that holds a very large number of elements, however when I run the below code, I get an error.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n
    
instance = test(10**20)
print(len(instance))
```

The error that I get back is:
OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer

Anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: what does `python -c "import platform; print(platform.architecture())"` show?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It shows: ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [``__len__`` can't return big numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60340710/len-cant-return-big-numbers)

Comment: Yes, thank you Mister Miyaki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CPython implementation detail. From the [`__len__` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__):

> In CPython, the length is required to be at most `sys.maxsize`. If the
> length is larger than `sys.maxsize` some features (such as `len()`)
> may raise `OverflowError`. To prevent raising OverflowError by truth
> value testing, an object must define a `__bool__()` method.

Comment: Ah okay, weird. Anyway I made a work around by renaming the __len__() function to just length() and using that instead. Thanks for the help